# Moderator political censorship?

Tags: discussion

What can be done about a moderator who makes a practice of deleting comments or posts s/he apparently disagrees with?  (Note that these are generally factual answers, not just expressions of opinion.)  This has been the ongoing (years, IIRC) practice of one particular person, and is getting rather annoying.

Comment: Why are you being politics into SE?  Unless the SE is specifically about politics?

Comment: First, **answers are never supposed to be posted in comments,** so those comments *may* have been removed on that basis. Further, without some specific examples that are concerning to you, there is no way to evaluate whether your assertion is correct. Links please.

Comment: You really need to be asking this on the site it occurred. If you think that you're not getting the response it warrants, I recommend contacting the CM team. Vaguestacking isn't really a great way to get your problem actually solved.

Comment: @Ramhound: Because the site (Skeptics) is one where many questions are political, or have a political dimension.

Comment: @Catija: If I ask the question on the site where it occurs, and I have done so a number of times, the person concerned makes some sort of vague excuse, or ignores/deletes the question.  Now I can understand that this might happen once in a while, but this is ongoing and frequent.

Comment: @Catija: I'm reluctant to post specific links or names because I'm asking what to do. I don't know how to properly go about posting a complaint, and don't see any obvious links.

Comment: Those questions are all answered by the duplicate... so it's sort of moot.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: I started a new thread because it's still an ongoing problem.  Indeed, there are uncounted instances where I haven't bothered to complain, since it seems pointless.  However, the new instance is somewhat different in that there does not seem to be any political motivation, just the moderator's opinion that there were too many comments.  The fact that (last I could see them, anyway) they were almost all interesting and/or relevant seems to have been completely missed :-(

Answer (score 17):

For Comments - Give them a pat on the head and tell them "Good Job"

Comments are meant to be transient, and for *clarifications* and other such things that don't quite fit into an answer. They're not meant to be something left for the long run. Clearing out comments is one of the things moderators do a lot.

As for posts - it depends. After quite a bit of time on these sites, I've found that scope, for questions and the definition of a valid answer varies. The best person to talk to in this case is the specific moderator.

Assuming that there's a sense that posts along a certain theme, in scope are deleted, it might be worth bringing it to the community in a clear, compelling meta post. It might *not* work always - for example, [Super User's policy on hackintosh questions wasn't changed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12050/revisit-the-hackintosh-policy), but it at least encourages discussion and visibility on the reasons for this. You might be convinced. You might not.

*Broad* meta posts like this arn't helpful IMO. They're primarily useful for hitting people over the head with inappropriately if folk fall for it. So, what can be done? Talk to them, make a specific case for these questions. *Help set the policy* by being constructive about the specific topic for posts, and why making a case for they shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Just because comments are designed to be transient doesn't mean it's okay for a moderator to delete them just because they don't like what they're saying.  If a comment is providing a critique of a post, or suggesting an improvement, it's *not* okay for a moderator to delete it without cause.  It still needs to actually be inappropriate, unnecessary, obsolete, etc.

Comment: He does say answers not opinions thought.

Comment: If the moderator feels that the comment isn't providing useful information that can be used to improve or respond to the post in question, then sure, they can delete it.  "I disagree with it" isn't a valid reason for deleting a comment.  Nor is your statement that no reason at all is needed, and that just because comments are designed to be temporary any deletion of any comment is automatically worthy of praise and a good thing.  Deletion is appropriate if the comment was either never helpful to begin with, or if it succeeded in getting the post in question improved, and is now obsolete.

Comment: No. But it isn't constructive is a good reason. OP's question is vague. If a comment was offensive to me, but not to a broader audience, I'd certainly get a second opinion.  That said needing to explain comment deletion would get old fast. Especially if it's mainly through more comments. It does feel like a broad question trying to back up a point.  I do think there's more to the story than op has in their question.

Comment: Sure, again, if there's a good reason for why the comment merits deletion, then it should be deleted.  You said in your answer that all comments always merit deletion at any time, and that there is *never* a situation where deletion of a comment is anything but "a good thing".  And that's not true.

Comment: Well I move comments worth keeping to chat sometimes and the mechanics of the sites discourage comment discussions threads like this one... So more often than not, it's a good thing

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: Perhaps I didn't write clearly enough.  The person concerned deletes both actual answers, and comments which would meet your standard.  (Regarding which, I think it would be a good idea to take a look at how most users actually use many of the sites.  Hold strictly to that standard, and most of the non-technical sites would become echoing voids.)  As for "moving to chat", that's just another way of deleting things, since chat is not usable.

Comment: You should bring up specific cases on the site. The point of moving to chat is to preserve information. Comments are meant for *clarification* not *conversation* anyway so "chat is not usable" is a wee bit of a argument that doesn't hold water with me. Other sites may disagree but its unlikely